# search dropdown results after rewriting url in .htaccess

Tags: ajax, .htaccess, search

i have a problem in search results from ajax after rewriting url in .htaccess
search was working perfect when the url was like

```
http://www.sitename.com/movie.php?name=gold
```

but now it has some bug after the url was rewritten in .htaccess

```
http://www.sitename.com/movie/gold
```

code 
.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]

# url movie rewrite
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+movie\.php\?name=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ movie/%1? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^movie/([^/]+)/?$ movie.php?name=$1 [L,QSA]
```

search.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.top-search input[type="text"]').on("keyup input", function(){
       /* Get input value on change */
       var inputVal = $(this).val();
       var resultDropdown = $(this).siblings(".result");
       if(inputVal.length){
           $.get("search.php", {term: inputVal}).done(function(data) 
{
               // Display the returned data in browser
               resultDropdown.html(data);
           });
       } else{
           resultDropdown.empty();
       }
   });

   // Set search input value on click of result item
   $(document).on("click", ".result p", function(){
       $(this).parents(".top-search").find('input[type="text"]').val($(this).text());
       $(this).parent(".result").empty();
   });
 });
```

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: please check the search bar from the header, working perfectly in this  http://www.jaisentertainment.com/
not working in this  http://www.jaisentertainment.com/movie/gold-2018-full-movie